# Function calling function in python

Tags: python

```
def one_good_turn(n):
  return n + 1

def deserves_another(n):
  return one_good_turn(n) + 2

print(one_good_turn(1))
print(deserves_another(2))
```

Since I have two function `one_good_turn(n)` and `deserves_another(n)` while calling function I had passed parameter `1` and `2`:

I expected the output to be:

```
2
4
```

but its shows:

```
2
5
```

Why is the output not what I had expected?

Comment: hmm. not sure why you're expecting 4 as the result of `deserves_another(2)` since you're adding 1 initially through `one_good_turn(2)`, which gives you 3, and then adding 2 afterwards, which yields 5.

Comment: Have you tried following the program execution on [PythonTutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit)?

Comment: "Why is the output not what I had expected?" Because somewhere you have a fundamental misconception. We can't tell you more, since you did not elaborate on why you expected these values.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you assume that `one_good_turn(n)` in `deserves_another(n)` will return the value that is previously computed. **No**. It gets the current input `n` which is `2`, call the function again, do `2+1` which is `3`. Then you add `3 + 2 = 5`.

Maybe to get your desired output, you should pass `1` to `deserves_another`:

```
def one_good_turn(n):
  return n + 1

def deserves_another(n):
  return one_good_turn(n) + 2

print(one_good_turn(1))  # 2
print(deserves_another(1))  # 4
```

A better way is to return the value from `one_good_turn` and pass it to `deserves_another`. So you don't need to call `one_good_turn` again inside `deserves_another`:

```
def one_good_turn(n):
  n = n + 1
  print(n)  # 2
  return n

def deserves_another(n):
  return n + 2

n = one_good_turn(1)
print(deserves_another(n))  # 4
```

Comment: Thanks Sir, I have some fundamental misconception but yours answer clear all my doubts.

Comment: Glad I could help you :)

Comment: def cube(number):
  return number * number * number

def by_three(number):
  return cube(number)    but Siir here it shows result 8 and 37 while passing parameter cube(2) and by_three(3) shouldn't by_three function should be 2 + 3 = 5 and it should print 125 result.

Comment: Did you mean `8` and `27`? `cube(2)` -> `2*2*2` -> `8`. `by_three(3)` -> `cube(3)` -> `3*3*3` -> `27`. Can't explain any better than this! Go through basics here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_functions.htm

Answer (score 0):

`one_good_turn(2)` returns 2+1=3.
Then the result is passed to `deserves_another`, which returns 3+2=5.